# How to reference view inside of a function?

Tags: python, django

I have a function that I need to call inside all of my Views that takes the view as the argument:

```
def view_1(request):

    def foo():
        return Model.objects.create(user = request.user, view = 'view_1')

    return render(request, myAPP/view_1.html)


def view_2(request):

    def foo():
        return Model.objects.create(user = request.user, view = 'view_2')

    return render(request, myAPP/view_2.html)

    .
    .
    .

def view_N(request):

    def foo():
        return Model.objects.create(user = request.user, view = 'view_N')

    return render(request, myAPP/view_N.html)
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate the view variable so that I can write the function once and call it within each view?

```
def view_1(request)
    foo()
    return render(request, myAPP/view_1.html)

def view_2(request)
    foo()
    return render(request, myAPP/view_2.html)
    .
    .
    .
def view_N(request)
    foo()
    return render(request, myAPP/view_N.html)
```

Comment: Did you check class based views?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just pass the function itself as an argument of `foo` ?

```
def foo(view_obj):
        return Model.objects.create(user = request.user, view = view_obj.__name__)

def view_1(request)
    foo(view_1)
    return render(request, myAPP/view_1.html)
```